# Get geometry for feature in Cesium3DTileset

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs, gltf

(CesiumJS Version 1.37)

I load a **batched 3D tileset** layer into CesiumJS; I am aware that I can access the content of every tile in that tileset using tile.content; in my case, every feature in that tile's content corresponds to a building. Reading all properties of a feature (=building) is really easy:

```js
var content = tile.content;
for (let i = 0; i < content.featuresLength; i++) {
  const feature = content.getFeature(i);
  const propertyNames = feature.getPropertyNames()
  const numProperties = propertyNames.length
  for(let j = 0; j < numProperties; j++){
    const propertyName = propertyNames[j]
    const propertyValue = feature.getProperty(propertyName)
    console.log('    ' + propertyName + ': ' + propertyValue)
  }
}
```

but now I seek a similarly easy-cheesy way to **get the geometry of a feature** (=building in  my case). I get the impression that this info is somewhat hidden, because the gltf (or rather glb) file that a batched 3D tileset layer references goes to the graphics card immediately and is inaccessible to me (?).

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a hack that works quite well. My problem had to do with the time at which I wanted to access the geometry for a feature (i.e. gltf), namely very much AFTER the content had been loaded. I found out that I can access the geometry AT LOADING TIME, though. So the whole problem turned into: "How can I intercept the loading process so that I can do my own analysis of the geometry at loading time".

Background: The geometry is stored in content._model.gltf. If content._model.releaseGltfJson is true, Cesium deletes the content._model.gltf (or the cache entry that this getter refers to) after loading.

My intercept was:

```
    // HACK!
    const oldB3dmFactory = Cesium.Cesium3DTileContentFactory.b3dm 
    Cesium.Cesium3DTileContentFactory.b3dm = function(tileset, tile, url, arrayBuffer, 
    byteOffset) {
        const content = oldB3dmFactory(tileset, tile, url, arrayBuffer, byteOffset)
        console.log("Cesium3DTileContentFactory.b3dm intercepted, so we can access the content with the GLTF")
        const gltf = content._model.gltf
        content.readyPromise.then(()=>{
            // _model.gltf is undefined because 
            // releaseGltfJson === true
            content.log(content._model.gltf)
        })
        return content
    }
```

Caveat: This only works for batched 3d tilesets (b3dm). You will need to replace `Cesium.Cesium3DTileContentFactory.b3dm` by `pnts`, `i3dm`, `cmpt` or `json` for this snippet to work with other types of geometry.